# Why does a selected image overflow the button border in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, cliptobounds

[image]

I am trying to create a profile image selection button. However, every time I select an image with UIImagePickerController, the image overflows the bottom of the button border. Is there a way to make sure the image stays within the border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set buttons clip to bounds true

```
button.clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Select clipToBounds from attributes section, or add `button.clipsToBounds = true` .
Try using `Autofit` as well. it is also available in `attribute` section on storyboard.